# Regex to parse equation

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse an equation such as

> 5x>=7-5y+4z

into a list of tuples with python:

```
[('', '5', 'x', '>='), ('', '7', '', ''), ('-', '5', 'y', ''), ('+', '4', 'z', '')]
```

I've managed to write a pattern (`pattern = "[+-]?\d*[a-z]?[><=]*"`) to break the equation into groups, but I have no idea how to make it return tuples.
Any help appreciated...

Comment: Your output format looks weird, is it really what you expect?

Comment: unfortunately, yes!

Comment: What is the logic though? I do not see the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([+-]?)([0-9]+)([a-z]?)([><]?=?)')
re.findall(pattern, '5x>=7-5y+4z')

>>> [('', '5', 'x', '>='), ('', '7', '', ''), ('-', '5', 'y', ''), ('+', '4', 'z', '')]
```

Each instance of the regex passed to `re.findall` is put into a tuple, which is then further split into strings corresponding to each of the groups in the regex.

I took some liberties with the interpretation of the actual regex, since I'm not sure what the expected output for other cases would be (for example, would there be a `0x` term?)